# How do I get data sent from Camera activity?

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I'm still fresh to Android programming and I don;t quite get how does Camera activity returns data.
I'm learning from video tutorials and I'm having problems understanding something, so there it goes (exceptions from code):

```
int cameraData = 0;

intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, cameraData);
```

I understand that this parts starts Activity with implicit intent and wait for Camera to return results

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
}
```

And this one waits for receives data from that Activity, where

- `requestCode` is 0 from `cameraData`
- `resultCode` is `RESULT_OK` if picture was taken
- `data` is data receiver from camera

I'm having difficulty with understanding `bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");`

How exactly should I know which String key to use to get particular data? I can't find information on what kind of data and in what form Camera returns results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) says that the "data" key holds a thumbnail and that if you need full image you should provide a filename by calling `putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f))` on your Intent, where f is a File.